# How do I properly use an array with JComboBox?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, jcombobox

I have been running into a few issues with my code regarding the implementation of a ArrayList into a JComboBox. I am capable of doing it by using code like `"roomList.addItem(selectedItem);` WITHOUT an array. What I am trying to accomplish is to use an arrayList to send new info to another part of the GUI so that I can use that array to save and load data whenever the user starts the GUI. The Question: **How do I properly use an array with JComboBox? I have seen a few tutorials, but I just can't seem to get the ComboBox to update with elements in the array.** I am making a mistake somewhere, if you could help I would be really grateful . :)

//This piece of code is from the main java file; array is in OrderSystem.java.

```
OrderSystem order = new OrderSystem();
ArrayList<String> list = order.getArrayList();
```

//retrieves the data selected from the JComboBox(different one) and adds it to the array list.

```
JComboBox<String> test = room.getRoomType();
String selectedItem = (String) test.getSelectedItem();
list.add(selectedItem);
```

Now, inside the OrderSystem.Java:
creates a ArrayList and JComboBox

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
JComboBox<Object> roomList;
...
setComboBox(new JComboBox<>(list.toArray()));
```

//setters and getters

```
public ArrayList<String> getArrayList(){
    return list;
}

public void setArrayList(ArrayList<String> list){
    this.list = list;


}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would use either a DefaultComboBoxModel object or create my own ComboBoxModel from the abstract class and use the ArrayList with that. For more detailed help if you don't get a great answer soon, consider creating and posting a [minimal code example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(list.toArray(new String[list.size()])));
```